# Connectivity issue for MySQL 8.0 and Node JS using Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, connectivity

I was trying out fetching the information from MySQL 8.0 table into Node JS using Express. But I am constantly getting the error ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE. I tried many things such as:

1. Changing the authentication method for an individual user (and used multiple different users) - changed it from SHA 256 to Caching 256 and to default one (mysql_native_password) neither of them works.
2. Changing my Node js code: instead of using the single connection which was giving me the error - PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR, I changed it to pool of connection but still getting the error ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_METHOD.

I found out that MySQL Server uses SHA 256 password private key and public key, but I don't know how to implement it or use it in Node. js.

My database table: react_test

product_id | product_name | product_price
1          | abc          | 10

Here is my Node.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

const SELECT_ALL_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM project.react_test';

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'localhost',
  user:'avd',
  password:'password',
  database:'project',
  insecureAuth : true
});

const pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host            : 'localhost',
  user            : 'avd',
  password        : 'password',
  authentication_string : 'root',
  insecureAuth : true
});

//var pool = mysql.createPool(connection);

connection.connect(err => {
  if(err) {
    return err;
  }
})

console.log(connection);
app.use(cors());
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.send('hello from product server')
});

app.get('/hola', (req,res) => {
  res.send('hola')
});

app.get('/hotels_info', (req,res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_QUERY, (err, results) => {
    if(err){
      return res.send(err)
    } else {
      return res.json({
        data: results
      })
    }
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
console.log('Product server listining port 4000');
});
```

Error when using single connection: {"code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR","fatal":false}

Error when using pool of connection:
{"code":"ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE","errno":1251,"sqlMessage":"Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client","sqlState":"08004","fatal":true}

I dont know what to do further! Please guide me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a connector for MySQL8 and nodeJS in [MySQL](https://mysql.com/) official website, you can find it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/nodejs/8.0.html You can download it using "npm i -s --save-exact @mysql/xdevapi" Here is the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/ This can be useful too:
https://insidemysql.com/introducing-connector-node-js-for-mysql-8-0/